# Which token from a long User-Agent should I use in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

The [definition of User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) states that several [tokens](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.8) can be included, as deemed necessary by the client.

I want to block certain bots via [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) and I am confused as to which part of the User-Agent string to use, especially for more obscure bots. For example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; uMBot-LN/1.0; mailto: crawling@ubermetrics-technologies.com)"
JS-Kit URL Resolver, http://js-kit.com/
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SEOkicks-Robot +http://www.seokicks.de/robot.html
```

Do I use the second token? Can tokens contain spaces, or did the SEOkicks folks forget a semicolon after *SEOkicks-Robot*? I don't actually intend on making my question specific to a couple bots - I want to know the guideline: which part of UA do I place in robots.txt for these exotic bots with UA as long as a [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku)?

```
User-agent: uMBot-LN/1.0
Disallow: /
```

PS: Thank you but I do not need to hear that undesirable bots are [better blocked with mod_security](https://serverfault.com/a/500035/34560). I already have commercial mod_sec rules in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web crawlers that support robots.txt often publish a page about their crawler with instructions about how to block the crawler in robots.txt:

- [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182072):

  > The Google user-agent is (appropriately enough) Googlebot.
- [Yandex](http://help.yandex.com/search/robots/request-rate.xml):

  > Examples: User-agent: Yandex
- [Yahoo](http://help.yahoo.com/l/nl/yahoo/ysearch/slurp/slurp-02.html):

  > Yahoo Slurp obeys the first entry in the robots.txt file with a User-agent containing "Slurp."

There is also a database of robot names that can be used in robots.txt on the robots website: http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html

Unfortunately, neither of the robots that you post as examples have pages that I could find, nor are they listed in the robots database.  However, as a pattern, I would expect that using a slash in the User-agent line of robots.txt would not be appropriate.  None of the examples that I have come across recommend that.  So I would use:

```
User-agent: uMBot-LN
Disallow: /

User-agent: SEOkicks-Robot
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no doubt I shouldnt use the semicolon. I mentioned it because the token to be used is **usually** the token which contains (what resembles) a botname (followed by a slash w/ version number when available), so I didn't think that the entire token is *SEOkicks-Robot +http://www.seokicks.de/robot.html*, but instead only *SEOkicks-Robot*. As for your answer, with the exception of omitting the version number, your guess seems as good as mine. But the goal of the question is to find out if there is a **standard** I can follow, instead of just guessing the proper token/section to use.

Comment: http://seokicks.de/robot.html confirms that it is *SEOkicks-Robot*.   If you don't have a URL for the robot, chances are that it is a rogue bot that doesn't implement robots.txt properly anyway and it doesn't matter what you put in the file. Legit bots have documentation.

Comment: I saw that, and it's what I am using. What about *JS-Kit URL Resolver, http://js-kit.com/*? There's got to be a standard, a guideline, of at least **what it should be**.

Comment: Notice how Yahoo also uses a "contains" rule for this case.  So you could say "Yahoo-Slurp" or "Yahoo Slurp/1.78" and they would still obey it.  Good crawlers will be liberal in interpreting the user-agent rules.